# How to i remove netcat addresses?

Tags: linux, networking

when I use this command in Server side (or client side): 
$nc -l 2380

and i don't use again this address:

```
$
$
$nc -l 2380 
nc: Address already in use
$
$
```

How to i remove the address?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried stopping the other netcat process listening on that port?

Comment: Yes, of course, I could not use that address after stopping it.

Comment: What does **netstat -anp | grep 2380** say?